# Periods in Django's SlugField

Tags: django, django-models, slug

### Question

- Why can data loaded via the `initial_data.yaml` fixture populate a SlugField with a slug containing a period and not generate an error?

### Code

Here's an excerpt of the model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    slug_code = models.SlugField(max_length=15)
```

Here's the applicable `initial_data.yaml` excerpt:

```
- model: myapp.project
  pk: 1
  fields:
    slug_code: TIDE.024
```

The yaml fixture `initial_data.yaml` is installed without any errors. When I log into the Admin and look at the Project model, I can see that the SlugField `slug_code` contains `TIDE.024`, but when I change the `slug_code` field to say `TIDE.025` the Admin generates the following error:

```
Enter a valid 'slug' consisting of letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens.
```

### Configuration

- Django v1.1.1
- PyYAML v3.09

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value in the `SlugField` is only checked in forms, not in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can always add a custom function if you want to forbid illegal characters from your field.

Something like:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    import re
    if re.search(r"[^-\w]",self.slug_field):
        raise Exception("This value can only contain letters, numbers, underscores, and dashes.")
    super(self, Project).save(*args, **kwargs)
```